# What's the highest precision achieved for an ADC?

Tags: adc, analog

I was browsing Digikey the other day (don't you?) and I stumbled across some 32bit ADCs, there were offerings from Linear, TI and Analog. One stood out, the AD7177 from Analog which states in Table 7 on page 19 of the [datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7177-2.pdf) that at 5 samples per second it's got a staggering 27.5 effective number of bits (and an RMS noise of 50 *nanovolts*). On the other hand of course, it's *accuracy* is significantly worse, but still.

This got me wondering, if a relatively cheap off-the-shelf ADC can hit an ENOB of 27.5 bits...

**What's the highest ENOB ever achieved?** Be it in some super integrated IC, some piece of stupidly expensive lab gear, a lock-in amplifier? **Has anyone ever beaten 27.5 bits of precision?**

[edit] A bit of clarification **I'm not looking to buy/build or otherwise aquire such a device** I'm just curious what the current state of the art is, modern atomic clocks have hit 3x10-18 (3 quintillionths) uncertainty, where do modern scientific voltmeters sit on the scale?

Comment: Unless there is an application, nobody will build anything better; why bother if nobody would buy it.

Comment: @PlasmaHH The fact that modern atomic clocks are measured to parts per quintillionth would imply that there are uses for insanely precise devices.

Comment: What kind of sample rate do you need? Precision is unlimited if sampling time is unlimited. Keep integrating for an hour and the result is pretty accurate.

Comment: @PkP I'm not looking for any sample rate, I'm just curious what the record is. Although presumably in reality there comes a point when you're limited by the device itself?

Comment: @Sam: building a bunch of (more or less) customized one of a kind things in a lab is hardly comparable to building an ADC IC that somebody needs to buy to be feasible. And with 32bit you are already well within thermal noises and stuff like that.

Comment: Those are sigma-delta ADC. You get high resolution with low bandwidth. Try getting 16bit at 100MSPS, suddenly it will not be a modest two-dollar toy.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I wasn't asking if it was something I could buy, I have no need for such a thing, I was just curious that "if a commercial unit can hit 27bits, what can a scientific unit achieve?"

Comment: Quote: "there comes a point when you're limited by the device itself?" Perhaps, perhaps not. Noise doesn't matter, it's integrated away. Actually noise is helpful as it varies the conversion result during integration so the ADC conversion value is not stuck in a single value.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: If an application needs many orders of magnitude of dynamic range, using a single 32-bit ADC whose specs are good near some particular value [either at one end of the range or the midpoint] but get worse at values which are far removed from it, may be easier and cheaper than having a lower-resolution ADC along with a programmable amplifier to ensure the signal is in a usable range.

Comment: 'effective resolution' (the 27.5) is not the same thing as ENOB. Short the input, measure RMS noise, divide by full scale voltage range.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany That's how they say the value was generated "The numbers given are for the bipolar input range with an external 5V reference. These numbers are typical and are 
generated with a differential input voltage of 0 V when the ADC is continuously converting on a single channel." So 5V reference, 50nV RMS noise, that's 100 million to 1 (ok, so that's 26.5 bits but still)

Comment: @sam It's effective resolution not ENOB. They do not use the term ENOB.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Well, now that I know that, but then what's the distinction then between the effective resolution and the effective number of bits?

Comment: @Sam: Accuracy vs precision perhaps?  If your transfer function is non-linear but smooth and monotonic, difference between two near measurements may have more "valid" bits than either of the readings taken alone.

Comment: ENOB = (SINAD-1.76)/6.02. SINAD (in dB) includes distortion and noise power- under dynamic conditions.

Comment: Some resources on ENOB vs. Effective resolution: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/5384, http://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/raqs/raq-issue-90.html

Comment: It would be worthwhile checking the academic literature for breakthroughs; proof-of-concepts are often a decade or more ahead of a commercial mass-market product (even if "mass-market" is some small niche like seismic monitoring)

Comment: Even on digikey, even mounted on an EVM board, it's not that ruinously expensive. Might just get one to play with!

Comment: You might be interested in the "volt-nuts" mailing list.

Comment: Note that as precision goes up, sampling rate will tend to go down, in large part because more time is required to get the value to "settle".

Comment: @Damien I agree, but unfortunately (and very sadly, IMO) most academic resources (scientific papers), are not accessible to people at large on the Internet. You usually have to register and pay a fee to access anything beyond the abstracts. I said *sadly* because today Internet affords something that was the dream of the past for research: easy communication of scientific results. Millions of eyeballs could scrutinize your work without complex bureaucratic and organization machinery. But this would impact the revenues of scientific journals, so no sorry, no free scientific communication. SAD!

Comment: IIRC the invention of ADC is marked by the invention of digital voltage meter. So it's safe to say a digital multimeter or voltage meter is an ADC. Then you have 8.5 digit digital multimeters which is around 27 bits. 8.5 digits is probably the limit of production DMMs now, which is probably the balance point of development cost and market value.

Answer (score 16):

Definition from [Wiki](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiErLPc8fDQAhVGXRoKHRndDlYQFggeMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FEffective_number_of_bits&usg=AFQjCNGgP-0paJTDZxDnihoMtmEAD2o5kg): -

> Effective number of bits (ENOB) is a measure of the dynamic range of
>   an analog-to-digital converter (ADC) and its associated circuitry. The
>   resolution of an ADC is specified by the number of bits used to
>   represent the analog value, in principle giving 2^N signal levels for
>   an N-bit signal

Quote from [Atmel](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi834vz8fDQAhVIrxoKHQX7A3MQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.atmel.com%2Fimages%2Fdoc8003.pdf&usg=AFQjCNF_A3E9IfV7OzWqyano1-aHRKseFA&bvm=bv.141320020,d.d2s): -

> In most cases 10-bit resolution is sufficient, but in some cases
>   higher accuracy is desired. Special signal processing techniques can
>   be used to improve the resolution of the measurement. By using a
>   method called 'Oversampling and Decimation' higher resolution might be
>   achieved, without using an external ADC.

[image]

Oversampling - take 4 consecutive samples and combine them to get one more bit of resolution; take a fairly standard 18 bit ADC and oversample by 256 to get a 22 bit ADC. Oversample by another 256 times to get a 26 bit ADC...

Do you see where this is going?

If noise is present and causes dithering of the signal, you can make any ADC have one extra bit by averaging/decimating 4 samples so, average as many as you like to get a higher resolution but clearly the price to pay is proportionally lower bandwidth and accuracy.

> What's the highest ENOB ever achieved?

What do you want it to be?

---

Footnote - a sigma delta ADC does exactly what I've described above except, it manages out of band noise much better and therefore gets a better yield on increased bits per converted samples averaged (or decimated).

It only uses a 1 bit ADC (a comparator) so clearly this technique works but it doesn't have to use a 1 bit ADC. It's all about noise filtering: -

[image]

The noise from a sigma delta ADC is progressively higher at higher frequencies due to the use of an integrator in the signal path - this forces noise to be low at low frequencies and, after decimation this yields a net benefit in resolution compared to just a conventional ADC that has been over-sampled and decimated.

Comment: Unless there is a typo in TI docs, probably an exponentiation was lost in copy-paste: `in principle giving 2N signal levels for an N-bit signal`. 2N should be 2^N.

Comment: @lorenzo well spotted.

Comment: @sam are we done with this question and answer now?

Answer (score 14):

It's possible to get around 32-bit effective resolution with an LTc (Low critical temperature) DC [SQUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQUID) (Superconducting Quantum Interference Device) using well-executed hybrid digital/analog techniques. A few \$\mu\Phi_0\$ RMS noise and, say, +/-10000 \$\Phi_0\$ range gives 32 bits with 1Hz bandwidth and 0.3Hz corner frequency. Actual critical current is at least an order of magnitude higher so a few more bits might be possible.

Good for making picovoltmeters and such like. Kind of expensive and inconvenient because of the 4K environment.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean with that uppercase PHI greek letter? Is it a typo or some constant related to the specific application?

Comment: @LorenzoDonati It's a constant- the magnetic flux quantum = h/2e where h is the Planck constant and e is the charge on an electron.

Comment: Yep! I was following the links in the article you linked to. I just found it here: [Magnetic flux quantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_flux_quantum). Ouch! Tough stuff! :-D

Comment: This surpasses the Turbo Encabulator's capability by varying the swaging angle of the dingle-arm and rendering the tremie pipe obsolete.

Comment: @Wossname The hardest part was aligning the hydrocoptic marzel vanes inside the cryostat.

Comment: Hmm.. why the downvote? This seems like a valid answer for an exotic ADC.

Answer (score 0):

Texas Instruments has an ADC with [31-bit resolution, ADS1282](http://www.ti.com/product/ADS1282), with up to 4000 samples per second, in industrial temperature range (-40 C + 85 C). Just ~$40 in qty. 1000. However, one needs to work really, really hard to get the analog front-end noise down to that level of resolution, although some sliding averaging might help at the expense of sampling rate and/or bandwidth.